# Read USB HID Device through RDP

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-desktop

I have a smart card reader connected to my computer which I want to be able to read from my VM (Windows Server 2016) which is connected through RDP. RDP does have an option to migrate USB devices, but I still couldn't see the smart card reader which is a HID device. Is there any way I could do this?